# Give UITextView a clickable URL link

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Hi I've been on this problem for a while now, I read a couple of posts already an I can't understand how to make a clickable `UITextView` that sends on internet. Here is my code:

```
func transformText(text: String, underlined: Bool, linkURL: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    if underlined{
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName , value: UIColor.lightGray, range: textRange)
    }
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName , value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 17)!, range: textRange)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName , value: UIColor.lightGray, range: textRange)
    if(linkURL != "")
    {
        let attrib = [NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: linkURL)!]
        attributedText.addAttributes(attrib, range: textRange)
    }
    return attributedText
}
```

Here is how i call it:

```
TextContent.attributedText = transformText(text: self.TelBox.TextContent.text, underlined: true, linkURL: "https://www.google.fr")`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why UITextField? It should be for editing, not selecting.

Comment: I'm so sorry I meant UITextView

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview?language=swift Set the delegate, implement it, and read the documentation because you need to set some property of your textView to some values.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder / Storyboard, or creating your `UITextView` via code?

Comment: I implemented it via code

Comment: you should use this: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel. It is in objective c but there is a lot of support for this project and even stackoverflow issues that will show you how to use it with swift

Comment: I sure will check it but isn't this dedicated to UILabels? thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Select the UITextView on storyboard and go to 'Show the Attributes inspector', then in 'behavior' unselects 'Editable' and in 'Data Detector' select 'Link'. Then go to 'Sohw the Identity inspector' and in 'traits' select 'Link' and 'Selected'.

Comment: thanks but as you can see all my code is done programmatically, plus I want to choose what link I put, not leave it to the detect protcocol

Answer (score 1):

You must set **editable** YES or set **selectable** YES

```
NSString *text = @"this is google web link";
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:dictionary];

textView.attributedText = attributeStr;

[attributeStr addAttributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]} range:[_readMessage rangeOfString:@"google web link"]];
textView.attributedText = attributeStr;

textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = YES;
textView.delegate = self;
```

google link will reponse by delegate

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is you want to make UITextView to make clickable requires you to make UITextView non editable because when you click on text it will lunch keyboard. To prevent this you can use

> textView.isEditable = false

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added this but the text is still not clickable.. when i added the NSLinkAttributeName the text highlighted but doesn't lead to anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've also enabled data type detection. For hyperlinks:

```
theTextView.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
```